# URL rewrite for category in layered navigation to external URL

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layered-navigation, url-rewrite

I'm trying to do a URL rewrite for 3 categories on the layered navigation to external URLs. I tried doing 301 redirects in the .htaccess file--that didn't work. I tried using Magento's URL rewrite management tool--that didn't work.

The link on the layered navigation is shows: http://dev.morrisononline.com/index.php/shop/petroleum-brands/76.html

I tried using this link, and it's category ID to do the rewrites and neither worked.

Help!

Comment: did you tried reindexing after changes in url rewrites?

Comment: That worked, thanks! Is there a way to make the link open a new tab instead of opening the external link in the same window?

Comment: Your other request is a new question, please ask it as a new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reindex after making changes in Url Rewrites. This will update the url of categories and even products.

Comment: could you pls help me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/210130/57334